# Issue with compiling OpenSludge

Tags: compiling, shared-library

I've tried compiling an adventure game sdk called OpenSludge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensludge/).
I can compile everything okay include [libalure](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/alure.html) through git (openal library).  But whenever I try to load this application it says it can't find the libalure.so.1 file.  I check in usr/local/lib directory and it is sitting there with it's symbolic link?

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try is:

```
ldconfig -vv | grep libalure
```

...
 libalure.so.1 -> libalure.so

This will tell you if your library is being dynamically linked, make sure you've got a reference to `/usr/local/lib` in your `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` as well

(it's now automatically referenced in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc`)